# javax.ejb.Timer gets restarted after a short period

Tags: java, timer, jboss

Here is my timer service inside a `@Stateless` bean.

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService;
```

I am creating a timer

```
int timeout = 10;
Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(timeout * 1000, timerId);
```

My timeout

```
@Timeout
public void handleTimeout(Timer timer){

   // This method process a task that requires
   // 60-80 minutes on an average

}
```

But strangely my `handleTimeout()` gets restarted after 5-6 minutes. After another 5-6 minutes it gets an `Exception` and stops processing.

I just want to run the method for an hour through the `@Timeout`. What am I missing here?

Obviously I can use Quartz or Async Task scheduler to overcome this. But want to know what is happening here with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, once again I have solved my problem. In my `Jboss7.1` `standalone.xml` file has the below thing that made my process gets timeout after 5 minutes.

```
<coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
```

I have increased this value to extend overall process and it worked. For example 3000 seconds for 50 minutes.

For my `Jboss EAP 6.2` I didn't need to change this configuration. Just adding this annotation over the method worked for me. **Note:** *this doesn't work at `Jboss7.1`*

```
// import javax.ejb.TransactionAttribute;
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
```

Hope someday my answer will help to somebody :-)